# Disable TCP keepalive on RHEL6

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, rhel-6

Is it possible to disable TCP keepalive on RHEL6?

I know the kernel parameters for tuning TCP keepalive timeout are as follows:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes
```

and that they can be modified via procfs and sysctl. To disable, is it simply a case of setting the `tcp_keepalive_probes` value to `0`?

Comment: Well, should be. You might use tcpdump or Wireshark to verify if it works.

Comment: From http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_timer.c#L616 I would say that yes, if you set keepalive_probes to 0 it will timeout rather than sending a keep alive request.

Comment: @ssnobody what I'm trying to achieve is a TCP connection which will stay open forever (or until it is closed normally) and will not send any probes. Do you know if this is achievable?

Comment: Sounds like you want to make your timeouts extremely large, such that they never trigger a close, instead. Possibly see http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning/ but overview shows you'd need to change the established connection timeout as well as the idle/time_wait timeout.